# how to Show the value in listbox where the value is from createNativeQuery Result on ZK?

Tags: web-applications, zk

iam getting very frustating problem when i have to show the value from result of createNativeQuery in Hibernate,my code is like this:

```
public List<Rmerchant> getListMerchantbyMasterMerchanttest(){
        List<Rmerchant> lstMerchant=em.createNativeQuery("select merchant_name,merchant_email,merchant_status from rmerchant where master_merchant_id=123")

                .getResultList();
        return lstMerchant;
    }
```

this is the simpe query because in advance i have to create more complex query like using count,and many function in query,and my code in ZK zul page like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?init class="org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.AnnotateDataBinderInit" arg0="./test"?>
<?init class="com.nsia.doku.escrow.controller.testController"?>
<zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul">
    <window id="test" xmlns:n="native" title="test" border="normal" position="center" apply="com.nsia.doku.escrow.controller.testController">
        <listbox  model="@{test$composer.lstMerchant}"
                vflex="true">
                <auxhead>
                    <auxheader colspan="3" class="topic">EDS Status</auxheader>
                </auxhead>
                <listhead>
                    <listheader label="Merchant Name"  align="center"/>
                    <listheader label="merchant email" align="center" />
                    <listheader label="merchant status"  align="center" />

                </listhead>
                <listitem self="@{each=lstMerchant}">
                    <listcell label='@[lstMerchant}' />
                    <listcell label='@{lstMerchant}' />
                    <listcell label='@{lstMerchant}' />
                </listitem>
            </listbox>

    </window>

</zk>
```

if the value is like what i write,the listcell will be like this:

```
merchant name                                  merchant email                                
[merch001, jhjhjh, null]                       [merch001, jhjhjh, null]                      
[fahmi0090908789788, fahmi@gmail.com, null]    [fahmi0090908789788, fahmi@gmail.com, null]
```

if the code i change in listitem like this:

```
<listitem self="@{each=lstMerchant}">
                    <listcell label='@[lstMerchant[0]}' />
                    <listcell label='@{lstMerchant[1]}' />
                    <listcell label='@{lstMerchant[2]}' />
                </listitem>

                or 
<listitem self="@{each=lstMerchant}">
                    <listcell label='@[lstMerchant["0"]}' />
                    <listcell label='@{lstMerchant["1"]}' />
                    <listcell label='@{lstMerchant["2"]}' />
                </listitem>

                or 
                <listitem self="@{each=lstMerchant}">
                    <listcell label='@[lstMerchant["merchant_name"]}' />
                    <listcell label='@{lstMerchant["merchant_email"]}' />
                    <listcell label='@{lstMerchant["merchant_status"]}' />
                </listitem>

                or

                every lstMerchant i change with each
```

is not working,aka the listitem show to row but the value is null,,iam so confuse about this problem,maybe somebody can help me?

i used to create web using icefaces,if in icefaces,i just have to place this tag in cell:

`currentRow[0]` but in Zk,i havent found it..

im sorry for my bad english and this newbie question..thanks..:D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok as i promise,the thing only i have to do is implements ListitemRenderer,and add the code like this to method render:

```
public void render(Listitem li, Object data) throws Exception {
        Object[] obj=(Object[]) data;
        new Listcell((String) obj[16]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[17]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[22]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[0]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[1]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[2]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[3]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[18]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[19]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[20]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[21]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[4]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[5]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[6]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[7]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[8]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[10]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[15]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[12]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[13]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[14]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[23]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[24]).setParent(li);
        new Listcell((String) obj[25]).setParent(li);


    }
```

the index is based on your column in your nativequery..

and in .zul page you only have to do this:

```
<listbox  model="@{dokureport$composer.lstTrans}"
                vflex="true" itemRenderer="@{dokureport$composer.itemRenderer}">
```

`itemRenderer` tag add default value `itemRenderer` and the `model` is list based on your controller..thanks for all of your response and sorry for my bad english..thanks..

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical scenario while associating UI components with a collection. You can refer [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/Data%20Binding/Associate%20UI%20Components%20with%20a%20Collection) for more details but basic idea is to access entity properties using dot . operator within your data-binding expression (Note: you have to have getter methods defined for these properties in your entity class). So in your case your listitem declaration should look something like this

```
<listitem self="@{each=merchant}">
                <listcell label='@{merchant.name}' />
                <listcell label='@{merchant.email}' />
                <listcell label='@{merchant.address}' />
            </listitem>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: many thanks for your response,is there a way just to access the data within collection without that getter setter?i know if the data is like that the binding is not a problem,but how if the query like this:
"select count(*) as total from merchant;"
if in icefaces, i just have to bind the list of selection from nativeQuery like that to the table and just have to call using
"currentRow[0]",if using hql,is not problem because i can map the object to the query result..i think this is so confusing,is there no way i can do this?

Comment: @fahmi isn't count(*) an aggregate function returning a single record? In that case it is completely different question than the original one here as it wouldn't work with ZK 'each' variable approach for iterating through collection assigned as model. You should start open a new question for that and provide more details.

Comment: thanks for your response,iam sorry maybe my question isnt clear but i have finish this problem,i will post it so maybe somebody have the same issue with me..thanks :D